# Satisfy & simple present

Tags: tenses

I am teaching simple present tense to my intermediate ESL students and was stumped by this question:  Why don't we use do/does in a question such as "What satisfies you?"  According to the rule, we should use do/does in questions with the verb base, as in:  "What does satisfy you?" Why does this seem to be an exception?
Thanks for your ideas!
Amy

Comment: Who says we ***don't*** use do-support with ***satisfy**?* Per the preceding sentence, it's often used to provide a suitable word that can be ***emphasised***. As, for example, *You say you're not into sex or drugs. What **does** satisfy you?* (emphatically contrasting what *does* with what *doesn't).*

Comment: @AmyM, Welcome to EL&U. Consider posting to English Language Learners

Comment: Thanks, Mustafa.  Is that a different exchange, or another part of this one?

Comment: Related ELL questions: [Do I have to use “do” in any “wh-” question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37902), [“Who pays” vs “who does pay”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78601) You don't need do-support because "what" is the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several conditions on the use of *Do*-Support in a clause:

1. Some operation must require an auxiliary verb
   (e.g, contraction of an auxiliary, or subject-auxiliary inversion).
2. There must be no auxiliary verb in the clause already.

*Not*, for instance, has to go after the first auxiliary verb, and invokes *Do*-Support with no auxiliary:

- *I like him, but she doesn't like him.*

Question formation (both Y/N and *Wh-*) uses subject-auxiliary inversion:

- *Does she like him? Yes, she likes him.*
- W*ho does she like? She likes him.*

**except** in *Wh-* questions where the *Wh*-word is the subject:

- *Who likes him? She likes him.*

In the example you give,

- *What satisfies you?*

*What* is the subject. Since it's already at the beginning of the clause, no further
movement is required to signal a question, so no subject-auxiliary inversion.
Therefore no *Do*-Support, either.